# Simple roulette simulator where the bet is always on odd, but it is infinite

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, simulation, nested-loops

Trying to create a roulette simulator that only bets on odd. Here is a sample execution:

```
Profit Goal: 150
Starting money: 100
Table minimum bet: 25
Table maximum bet: 300
Spin: 16. You lost $25 on the bet. You had 100. Now you have 75 left.
Spin: 22. You lost $50 on the bet. You had 75. Now you have 25 left.
Spin: 33. You won $25 on the bet. You had 25. Now you have 50 left.
Spin: 1. You won $25 on the bet. You had 50. Now you have 75 left.
Spin: 29. You won $25 on the bet. You had 75. Now you have 100 left.
Spin: 15. You won $25 on the bet. You had 100. Now you have 125 left.
Spin: 3. You won $25 on the bet. You had 125. Now you have 150 left.
You reached your goal and beat the casino. You should stop now. You have $150.
```

My Code

```
import random
random.seed(5)

Profit_Goal = int(input('Profit Goal:'))
Starting_Money = int(input('Starting money:'))
Table_Min = int(input('Table minium bet:'))
Table_Max = int(input('Table maximum bet:'))
Bet = Table_Min
Money = Starting_Money
while 0 < Money <= Profit_Goal:
    number = random.randint(1, 36)
    print('Spin:', number)
    if number % 2 != 0:
        Money = Money + Bet
        print('You won', Bet, 'on the bet. You had', Money, 'Now you have', Bet + Money)
    elif number % 2 == 0:
        Money = Money - Bet
        Bet = Bet * 2
        print('You lost', Bet, 'on the bet. You had', Money, 'Now you have', Money - Bet)
    elif Money >= Profit_Goal:
        print('You reached your goal and beat the casino. You should stop now. You have', Money)
    else:
        print('You have lost all of your money')
```

The code loops non stop, but I dont know why. Please help

Comment: I don't understand the example. Why did it stop when it reached $150 if the goal is $1500?

Comment: It doesn't look like your code will produce that output. Is the text just a possible expected output?

Comment: Your last two branches will never execute because your first two branches are always true. The number is either even or odd and the rest will be skipped .The last two branches should be individual ifs, not Elif not Else.

Comment: And the first `elif` should just be `else:` -- if the number isn't odd, it must be even.

Comment: I think the example is formatted wrong. I think the goal should be 150.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your stated symptoms. So far, your program always stops.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue in your code with the elif conditions. The condition elif Money >= Profit_Goal should be an independent if statement because you want to check this condition after each spin, not just when the number % 2 == 0 condition is met.

```
import random

Profit_Goal = int(input('Profit Goal: '))
Starting_Money = int(input('Starting money: '))
Table_Min = int(input('Table minimum bet: '))
Table_Max = int(input('Table maximum bet: '))
Bet = Table_Min
Money = Starting_Money

while 0 < Money < Profit_Goal:
    number = random.randint(1, 36)
    print('Spin:', number)
    if number % 2 != 0:
        Money = Money + Bet
        print('You won', Bet, 'on the bet. You have', Money, 'Now you have', Bet + Money)
    elif number % 2 == 0:
        Money = Money - Bet
        Bet = Bet * 2
        print('You lost', Bet, 'on the bet. You have', Money, 'Now you have', Money - Bet)
    if Money >= Profit_Goal:
        print('You reached your goal and beat the casino. You should stop now. You have', Money)
        break
else:
    print('You have lost all of your money.')
```

Comment: The money goes over the profit goal still

Answer (score 0):

> *"... The code loops non stop, but I dont know why. ..."*

It's working correctly here.

Here is an output.

```
Profit Goal:1500
Starting money:1000
Table minium bet:25
Table maximum bet:50
Spin: 17
You won 25 on the bet. You had 1025 Now you have 1050
Spin: 23
You won 25 on the bet. You had 1050 Now you have 1075
Spin: 34
You lost 50 on the bet. You had 1025 Now you have 975
Spin: 2
You lost 100 on the bet. You had 975 Now you have 875
Spin: 30
You lost 200 on the bet. You had 875 Now you have 675
Spin: 16
You lost 400 on the bet. You had 675 Now you have 275
Spin: 4
You lost 800 on the bet. You had 275 Now you have -525
Spin: 11
You won 800 on the bet. You had 1075 Now you have 1875
Spin: 8
You lost 1600 on the bet. You had 275 Now you have -1325
Spin: 24
You lost 3200 on the bet. You had -1325 Now you have -4525
```

Here are some recommendations for your code, if you're finding it's not running correctly.

You're displaying the incorrect *Money* value after each spin.

Adjust *Money* and *Bet* after the *print* call.
And, utilize a *[format-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)*, which can help readability.

```py
if number % 2:
    print(f'You won {Bet} on the bet. You had {Money} Now you have {Money + Bet}')
    Money += Bet
elif not number % 2:
    print(f'You lost {Bet} on the bet. You had {Money} Now you have {Money - Bet}')
    Money -= Bet
    Bet *= 2
```

Additionally, evaluate *Money* over *Profit_Goal*, after the *loop*.

```py
while 0 < Money < Profit_Goal:
    number = random.randint(1, 36)
    print('Spin:', number)
    if number % 2:
        print(f'You won {Bet} on the bet. You had {Money} Now you have {Money + Bet}')
        Money += Bet
    elif not number % 2:
        print(f'You lost {Bet} on the bet. You had {Money} Now you have {Money - Bet}')
        Bet *= 2
        Money -= Bet
if Money >= Profit_Goal:
    print('You reached your goal and beat the casino. You should stop now. You have', Money)
else:
    print('You have lost all of your money')
```

Output

```
Profit Goal:1500
Starting money:1000
Table minium bet:25
Table maximum bet:50
Spin: 17
You won 25 on the bet. You had 1000 Now you have 1025
Spin: 23
You won 25 on the bet. You had 1025 Now you have 1050
Spin: 34
You lost 25 on the bet. You had 1050 Now you have 1025
Spin: 2
You lost 50 on the bet. You had 1025 Now you have 975
Spin: 30
You lost 100 on the bet. You had 975 Now you have 875
Spin: 16
You lost 200 on the bet. You had 875 Now you have 675
Spin: 4
You lost 400 on the bet. You had 675 Now you have 275
Spin: 11
You won 800 on the bet. You had 275 Now you have 1075
Spin: 8
You lost 800 on the bet. You had 1075 Now you have 275
Spin: 24
You lost 1600 on the bet. You had 275 Now you have -1325
You have lost all of your money
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Reilas for the hepful output. I made some more tweaks but I fixed my issue. Still kinda messy but it works lol!

'''import random

random.seed(5)

Profit_Goal = int(input('Profit Goal: ')) Starting_Money = int(input('Starting money: ')) Table_Min = int(input('Table minimum bet: ')) Table_Max = int(input('Table maximum bet: '))

Bet = Table_Min Money = Starting_Money print(f'Starting Money:', Starting_Money)

while 0 < Money <= Profit_Goal:
Bet = Table_Min

```
if(Money == Profit_Goal):
    break

while 0 < Money <= Profit_Goal:
    number = random.randint(0, 36)
    if (Money == Profit_Goal):
        break

    print('Spin:', str(number) + '.',  end='')

    if number % 2:
        print(f' You won ${Bet} on the bet. You had {Money}. Now you have {Money + Bet} left.')
        Money += Bet
        break

    elif not number % 2:
        print(f' You lost ${Bet} on the bet. You had {Money}. Now you have {Money - Bet} left.')
        Money -= Bet
        if Bet * 2 > Money:
            Bet = Table_Min
        else:
            Bet *= 2
```

if Money >= Profit_Goal:
print(f'You reached your goal and beat the casino. You should stop now. You have ${str(Money)}.') else:
print('You ran out of money')'''